# ¿Como puedo crear una consulta de una relación ManyToMany?

Tags: java, spring

Tengo una tabla `persons` la cual tiene una relacion `ManytoMany` con `Projects` es decir una persona puede tener muchos proyectos y un proyecto muchas personas, por lo que `hibernate` crea una tabla `person_project`con el `id_project` y `id_person`, lo que no se es como hacer la consulta para luego mostrar los proyectos que tiene asignado una persona.

Fragmento del modelo Person:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "persons", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
```

Metodo get de ProjectController:

```
@GetMapping("/projects/person/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getProjectByPersonId(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long personId) {
    try {
        List<Project> projects = service.findAllByPerson(personId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(projects);
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

Entidad project

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7491360757381283798L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 150)
@NotNull(message = "El campo nombre es requerido")
private String name;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "person_project", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")})
private Set<Person> persons =new HashSet<>();
```

Entidad personas

```
@Entity
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1984082712283700763L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name = "name", length = 50)
@NotNull(message = "El campo nombre no puede estar vacio.")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "persons", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Audited(targetAuditMode = NOT_AUDITED)
private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consulta:

```
SELECT per.name, proj.name FROM Project proj, Persona per WHERE per.id=proj.id_person AND proj.id=per.id_project;
```

**Código java.**

```
package com.codemonkey.repository;

import com.codemonkey.entity.Project;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT proj.name , pers.name FROM Project proj, Person per WHERE per.id=:id_person AND proj.id=:id_project")
    public List<Project> find(@Param("id_person") long id_person,@Param("id_project") long id_project);
}
```

No lo he probado, pero creo puede servirte.

Comment: y cual tendria que ser la condición en este caso?

Comment: Tu "id" que necesitas buscar.

Comment: Puedes postear tus entidades para tener más claro tu problema.

Comment: ahí edité la pregunta

Comment: Edité la respuesta.